# Magento 2.4.3 - site becomes unstable / unresponsive when in production mode

Tags: developer-mode, production-mode, magento2.4.3

Have recently updated site from M2.3.5 to M2.4.3

While in developer mode, the site is responsive and stable.

If I switch to production mode, then after a period of time it becomes unresponsive and just hangs...  Restarting apache doesn't resolve the issue, but a full server reboot does.

There are no spikes in memory usage or CPU etc at the time that it hangs

Checked magento & apache error logs / syslog and can't see anything that would explain what's going on.

Am I right in thinking I don't get the same level of debugging logs in production mode as I do in developer mode?

Can anyone point me in the direction of where I can look for the issue OR advise on why it is that production mode might experience issues when dev mode is fine?

Thanks!

Comment: its weird. please unmerge and unminify css/js and Disable bundling too and Try once.

Comment: Have you resolved your unstable-unresponsive condition?